# Pointer in struct question. Have I done it correct?

Tags: c

I am rewriting some code from having a regular pointer to where the pointer is in a struct.

This is the original code which works:

```
int wrote = sf_writef_double(outfile, *mono_channel, frames);
```

In the new code, where I have put the mono_channel pointer in a struct have I written

```
int wrote = sf_writef_double(outfile, data->mono_channel, frames);
```

The compiler doesn't complain, but the program crashes.

So the question is. Is `data->mono_channel` the same as `*mono_channel`?

Hugs,
Louise

**Edit:**
To be more precise here is what I do:

```
ltfat_complex* fm;
fm = malloc(data->L * sizeof(ltfat_complex));
if (fm == NULL) { puts("fm malloc failed"); exit(1); }

/* Writes output to fm */      
idgt_fac(data->coef, gdf, data->L, 1, 1, data->a, data->M, fm);

free(data->mono_channel);

data->mono_channel = (double*) fm;
free(fm);
```

...

```
int wrote = sf_writef_double(outfile_handler, data->mono_channel, frames);
```

Could the problem be, that I try to re-use the `data->mono_channel` pointer?

**Edit2:**
Here are the entire source codes (~ 700 lines each):

Old which works:
http://www.student.dtu.dk/~s011392/gabor-io.zip

New:
http://www.student.dtu.dk/~s011392/gui.zip

Sadly they require a lot of libraries to compile: ltfat from SVN, fftw3, lapack, blas, sndfile.

But there tey are =)

Comment: The problem here is `free(fm)`. That also frees `data->mono_channel`, so you can't use it later.

Comment: WOW! You are right. That fixed it =) Thanks a lot! I had spend all night looking at that. I am new here at Stack Overflow. Can I give you points?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way to give points for a comment. And he already has the only badge that you can get for making good comments.

Comment: Sorry, for asking these novice questions. To the left of each comment is there a arrow up. Should I click on that every time I see a good comment? Am I suppose to be able to click as many times as I want on the arrow up on the answers?

Comment: If you like something, click the up arrow (once). Any other questions about the site can be asked here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dereferencing `mono_channel` in the first version but not in the second. Try

```
int wrote = sf_writef_double(outfile, *(data->mono_channel), frames);
```

Comment: If I do that I get this compiler error:

audio_save.c:25: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘sf_writef_double’
/usr/include/sndfile-64.h:517: note: expected ‘const double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
make: *** [audio_save.o] Error 1

Any idea what then could be the problem?

Comment: Was `mono_channel` of the exact same type that `data->mono_channel` is?

Comment: int wrote = sf_writef_double(outfile, &data->mono_channel, frames)

Comment: Sorry, sounds like you actually have a deeper problem.  What exactly does sf_writef_double expect - an array of doubles, or a single double?  If an array, then look at how you've setup your struct - you problably need its member to a be a pointer to doubles, and that pointer needs to be allocated just as the old plain pointer was (i.e. it needs to be assigned the array of doubles at some point before calling the above function)

Comment: Yes, the types are the same. Both doubles. But I try and re-use the mono_channel pointer, which might then be the problem? I have added the code snippet to the question, and added the entire source, for both cases. ~ 700 lines each. Is the re-use of pointers legal?

Answer (score 2):

No, data->mono_channel and *mono_channel are not the same thing. *(data->mono_channel) is the same as *mono_channel.

I really wonder how you got by with *mono_channel in your program if you wanted to pass a pointer to a double instead of a double. Clearly mono_channel was a pointer to a pointer to a vector of doubles. Most likely mono_channel was a pointer to an array (which is actually a vector) of doubles.

```
double *mono_channel[1000];   // let's say
```

Anyway, if you're crashing, it's probably because you haven't allocated any storage and pointed mono_channel to it, instead you've just defined it as a member of your struct that is a double * and are using it. You either need to point mono_channel to a predefined global array or allocate it with malloc/new.

Comment: +1 for going into detail. (My brain is fried right now from working with VBA all day.)

Comment: Now that you mention it, I wonder too why it worked in the original. The sndfile specs says:
sf_count_t  sf_writef_double (SNDFILE *sndfile, double *ptr, sf_count_t frames) ;
I have linked to the source code in the question, is case you can see what's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`data->mono_channel` is the same as `(*data).mono_channel`

If you want the contents of the pointed to variable I suggest you want `*(data->mono_channel)`

You may want to re-read K&R.